# Rewrite jQuery to scroll left and right

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I need help rewriting my jQuery.  I have four links at the top: "One, Two, Three, Four"

When you go from One --> Two, it wipes in from the right.  Perfect!

When you go from Two --> One, it wipes in from the right.  Not ideal.  I would like it to swipe in from the left instead.

And so on based on the position of each.  Is this easy?

http://jsfiddle.net/5N3YK/126/

HTML:

```
<a data-section="one" href="#">One</a>
<a data-section="two" href="#">Two</a>
<a data-section="three" href="#">Three</a>
<a data-section="four" href="#">Four</a>

<div id="hello">
    <section id="one" class="active">One</section>
    <section id="two">Two</section>
    <section id="three">Three</section>
    <section id="four">Four</section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#hello, #hello section{
    min-width: 350px;
    height:330px;
    background:green;
}

#hello section{
    position: absolute;
    left:100%;
}

#hello{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:90%;
}

#hello section:nth-child(1){left:0%}
```

jQuery:

```
$('a').on('click', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var sectionId = $(this).attr("data-section"),
        $toSlide = $("#hello section#" + sectionId),
        $fromSlide = $('.active');

    if (!($toSlide.hasClass("active"))) {

        $fromSlide.animate({
            "left": "-100%"
        }, 500, 'linear')
        $toSlide.animate({
            "left": "0%"
        }, 500, 'linear', function() {
            $fromSlide.css("left", "100%");
            $fromSlide.removeClass("active");
            $toSlide.addClass("active");
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @James - this one will not perform exactly like you want, but it's small, simple and slides! (just a bit more than yours :)

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/emexug/1/edit)*

This is all you need:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">One</a>
<a href="#">Two</a>
<a href="#">Three</a>
<a href="#">Four</a>

<div id="hello">
    <section>One</section>
    <section>Two</section>
    <section>Three</section>
    <section>Four</section>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#hello').stop().animate({scrollLeft: $(this).index() * $('#hello').width() },700);
});
```

**CSS**

```
#hello, #hello section{
    min-width: 350px;
    height:330px;
    background:green;
}   
#hello{
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:90%;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
section{
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    zoom:1;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-right:-4px;
}
```

Comment: While nice, this code doesn't have the same functionality as the original post. If you go from One->Four on the original post, it doesn't slide through two and three. Yours does. Nice work, otherwise, roXon, and maybe it'll still work for what he wants to do!

Comment: Thanks! Doing my best! ;) @James, I know exactly what the OP tried to do, but for just a small change (a longer scroll way) we minified all our problems and have a happy client!

Comment: @roXon One more question.  If I wanted to center this and also add a max width.. something like this:  width: 95%; /*width: 480px;*/
 min-height: 500px;
 max-width: 480px;
 margin: 8px auto;   Where would I add it?

Comment: Again, excellent Jquery @roXon; I couldn't possibly write anything that simple and clean. However, I tried my best and made some ugly code that tried to preserve the original functionality, just in case he (or someone else asking the question) wants to keep it.

Answer (score 1):

This code isn't quite as pretty as roXon's, but preserves the original scrolling mechanism. roXon's code will scroll through all the different options when you go from, say, one to four, whereas this one will jump right to four.

[Check it out here.](http://jsfiddle.net/9bKxS/)

Edit: Please note that this code isn't flawless. I added a partial fix to roXon's excellent debugging results below, but it still doesn't quite hold up to maniacal clicks. If this is what you're going for, you'll want to fix it up just a bit more so that it handles crazy clicking.

Comment: Nice try! but **Your code does not work**. it's not bulletproof. Try to click maniacally on all the links, at some point the slides will get messed!

Comment: That's also nice and you're right it does perserve my original.  However I didn't know what I was doing and what I wanted.  roXon was more correct.  Thanks though!

Comment: Good call @roXon! I added a partial fix and made a note of the results of your debug. user104, I'm glad your original concern was solved.

Comment: Nice work again, @roXon, but it still seems to be sliding all of the previous ones across...it just slips them by quickly? When I go from, say, Four to One, I think I see a Three sneak past.

Comment: @James, true but it was just a quick try